# Why should I cast Promise<void> to Promise<any>?

Tags: typescript, promise

I wrote an async generator that returns promises.

```js
function convert(): Promise<void> { return null; }

async function* conversions(): AsyncIterableIterator<Promise<void>> {
  await convert();
  yield convert(); // error TS2322: Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Promise<void>'.
  yield convert() as Promise<any>;
}
```

I thought there should be no error. Why TS2322 occurs?

Comment: I found the problem, and it seems duplicate..

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncIterableIterator`'s generic parameter stands not for promise, but for the internal value, which can be acquired by `await`ing this iterator. So, this code works:

```
function convert(): Promise<void> { return Promise.resolve(); }

async function* conversions(): AsyncIterableIterator<void> {
  await convert();
  yield convert();
}
```

Side note: as you can see, your variant of `convert` function did not compile, so I changed it a bit to eliminate the error.

---

To get the sense of how this all works, let's add some meaningful return type to our iterator. Something like this:

```
async function convert(): Promise<number> { return 0; }

async function* conversions(): AsyncIterableIterator<number> {
    await convert();
    yield convert();
}

async () => {
    const num: number = (await conversions().next()).value;
}

const num: Promise<number> = conversions().next().then((ret) => ret.value);
```

You can see that `await`ing your iterator returns the type specified in it, while simply calling `next` will return the promise which should be followed with `then` to retrieve the value (in fact, again, the promise of the value).

Comment: Then does awaiting your `conversions` return a promise?

Comment: Sorry, does `(await conversions().next()).value` return a promise?

Comment: Of course not. If `func` returns the `Promise<T>`, then `await func()` returns `T`. The same is here - I'll update the answer in a moment.

Comment: Maybe there is a lack of my description to my question. Thanks for a kind reply.